# Install font as shortcut for all user using powershell script

Tags: powershell, fonts

I need to **install the font as shortcut for all the users** instead of installing it directly.

Refer my code

```
$objShell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$objFontFolder = $objShell.Namespace(0x14)
$newFontFiles = Get-ChildItem $(FontsSourceFolder)
foreach ($newFontFile in $newFontFiles)
{
    $objFontFolder.CopyHere($newFontFile.FullName)
}
```

I want to install the font as shortcut like below below highlighted option

[image]

Suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make a hardlink using `new-item` and drop it in the public folder so all users get it.

Comment: "Install as shortcut for all users"?  What does that do and why would you want to do that for a font?

Comment: Have a look here for installing the font with the newer Windows updates  https://jordanmalcolm.com/deploying-windows-10-fonts-at-scale/

Comment: Do you guys meant that we can achieve it by using "New-ItemProperty" ? But I thought that is only for register the font. Please correct me if am wrong. 

@Daniel to answer your question, When we use "Install as shortcut for all users" in the registry, Data will have the "full path of font"(it can be anywhere) but default it will have only the "font name"